# How does Excel 2010 use RAM?

Tags: microsoft-excel, memory, microsoft-excel-2010

Using 32 bit Excel 2010 I only have 2G RAM availiable, even if I have 16G available on my PC.

My question is:

If I open up a second instance of Excel ( not a second workbook but re-open the whole program again ) do they each use 2G of RAM, or share 2G of RAM ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The 2 GB that a process can use on 32-bit Windows is not "RAM". It is virtual address space, and it is simply the upper limit; most instances of most programs will only use a fraction of that.

However each instance of Excel that is in its own process (as shown in Task Manager's "Processes" column on Win7, "Details" on Win10)  does have the ability to use *up to* 2 GB of virtual address space.

If you open multiple spreadsheets within the same Excel.exe process those are *not* separate instances, and all that work is then done within the same process address space (2 GB virtual max).

The relationship of virtual address space to RAM is very "soft". Creating a process - which, like all processes running on 32-bit Windows, *may* use up to 2 GB V.A.S. (but most will not) - does not inherently use any particular amount of RAM, aside from a small amount (under a megabyte)) for nonpageable kernel data structures that manage the process.

RAM is allocated to processes on an on-demand basis. Typically only around a tenth to a quarter of a process's virtual address space (which, again, will not be 2 GB per; it will be whatever is needed for the processes' code and data) will be occupying RAM. How much depends on how much of its v.a.s. it is actively accessing, and on how much RAM is available. The more RAM is available, the more RAM each busy process is allowed to use - that is, the more of each process's virtual address space will be "resident" in RAM at any moment. The observed RAM usage of a process, and of Windows itself, is very much dependent on circumstance: How much RAM the machine has, and how busy other processes are.

Like every other executable on Windows, if you run more than one instance of a process, the portions of the code that have been brought in to RAM for each instance will be accessible to the other(s). So while each will live in its own virtual address space, they will not occupy multiple sets of RAM for their code; the code is shared in RAM. On the other hand, data that is specific to each instance occupies both virtual address space and RAM separately for each process.

The "2 GB" limit on virtual address space described in all of the above can be 4 GB if it's a 32-bit app that is "large address aware" and running on 64-bit Windows.

Comment: thanks, just wanted to know as I run some hefty macros each morning one after another, knowing this I will now be able to run 3 at once, while I go for breakfast :)

Comment: Assuming you don't have some other huge processes running, you shouldn't have any trouble with three instances in a machine with 16 GB RAM.